# Can I delete the Document Conversions User Account

Tags: installation, user-accounts, windows-7

I have looked over the site, but couldn't find the answer to this...

I just installed ***SharePoint 2010*** on my ***Windows 7*** machine for development. I restarted the machine and a new user was added, ***Document Conversion User Account***.

I have installed SharePoint on a server before and this user account wasn't created. Maybe I chose different options...

Do I need this account? May I delete it? If I do delete it, will it cause problems down the road?

Comment: I have had the same experience, and also didn't find much in the way of information about it. Can anyone enlighten us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not, but you can still update the Service account used via Central Admin > Security > Configure Service Accounts (have a look here http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2010/10/service-accounts-and-managed-service-accounts-in-sharepoint-2010/), but please note (if you still want to use the services) that

- Service accounts for Document Conversion must remain on it’s default
  setting, because the load balancer service needs to run as **network
  service**
- The **launcher service needs to run as Local System (not
  LocalService)** on every machine that you want to run conversions on.